# inotifywait ignore new directory

Tags: linux, inotify

I'd like to ignore a directory that has not been created at the time I start `inotifywait`. I have an empty directory `test`:

```
ubuntu@foo:~$ ls -lah test/
total 8.0K
drwxrwxr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Sep  5 20:00 .
drwxr-x--- 13 ubuntu ubuntu 4.0K Sep  5 19:56 ..
```

I start `inotifywait` like this:

```
ubuntu@foo:~$ inotifywait -mr -e CREATE -e MODIFY -e DELETE -e MOVE /home/ubuntu/test/ @/home/ubuntu/test/log
Setting up watches.  Beware: since -r was given, this may take a while!
Watches established.
```

Then, in another terminal, I create a directory `log` and put some content there:

```
ubuntu@foo:~/test$ mkdir log
ubuntu@foo:~/test$ cd log/
ubuntu@foo:~/test/log$ echo "foo" > foo
```

This is the `inotifywait` output:

```
/home/ubuntu/test/ CREATE,ISDIR log
/home/ubuntu/test/log/ CREATE foo
/home/ubuntu/test/log/ MODIFY foo
```

However, if I close the script and start it again and put some more content into the file, no events are triggered.

Is it possible, to ignore a "soon to be created"-directory in inotifywait?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily done by replacing the `@` exclusion prefix by the `--exclude` option with a simple pattern (regular expression). For example,

```
--exclude /home/ubuntu/test/log'$'
```

By adding a `$` (match end-of-string) we ensure that creating a file such as `test/log2` is not also wrongly matched and excluded. Also add a `^` at the start to ensure we don't match the path at some greater depth:

```
--exclude '^'/home/ubuntu/test/log'$'
```

The exclusion of the directory is sufficient to exclude new files under it, **unless** the directory already exists, bizarrely. To cope with that case, replace the `$` by an alternate `$` or `/`, i.e. `($|/)`:

```
--exclude '^'/home/ubuntu/test/log'($|/)'
```

However, testing seems to show that (for my version 3.14?) only the last `--exclude` option is used, which is not documented, and rather unexpected.
So if you have several directories to exclude, you need to combine them into a single regexp. This does not need to be complicated if you are not familiar with the syntax, simply put the list inside `^(...|...|...)($|/)`, for example:

```
--exclude '^(/home/ubuntu/test/log|/home/abc/log|/usr/def)($|/)'
```

If your paths contain special regexp characters like `.[]^$()*+?|{},` you need to look up how to escape them.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works like a charm!